# Neo4j: reason behind first letter uppercase in labels?

Tags: syntax, neo4j

Since I was thinking about not following their suggestion, as it seems like making my code only more complex for nothing, I'd like to know if anybody knows why Neo4j devs suggest to declare labels with first letter uppercased. (I use Neo4j trough rest calls. I thought that maybe had something to do with Java syntax?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a lot of the convention is:

- use upper case for relationship types
- use camel case for properties

In order to distinguish labels from these two, first letter uppercase for labels is what we thought a good practice.

However nothing prevents you from using a different convention.

Answer (score 1):

The labels can be thought of as object classes or interfaces. The UpperCamelCase naming convention is often used for those cases in a lot of programming languages (Java, JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, Python, ...)

Keep in mind that this is a convention, not a requirement. **The most important part in any project is consistency. *Use a coding style and stick to it throughout!***

Neo4j naming convention:

- Labels: UpperCamelCase (a.k.a. PascalCase)
- Relationships: CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORE
- Property key names: lowerCamelCase or snake_case

Cypher examples:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:MEMBER_OF {start_date:20131031}]->(:WorkGroup {name:"Dev"});
```

Alternatively:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:MEMBER_OF {startDate:20131031}]->(:WorkGroup {name:"Dev"});
```

References:

- [The Neo4j Developer Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/#_label_names)
- [The O'Reilly Graph Databases - Neo4j Graph Database](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/)